Vitest snapshot: unsorted html attributes
I am running a vitest to test if a vue component match an snapshot.
The vue component use javascript flatpickr component to generate a datepicker.
The snapshot is generated with another environment and it generates the html attributes in a different order:
Here you are the original html generated:
<input data-v-7f26d67d="" id="datepicker" class="form-control flatpickr-input" type="text" readonly="readonly">

And the html generated right now:
<input data-v-7f26d67d="" id="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control flatpickr-input" readonly="readonly">

As you can see it only change the position of the type attribute. Html attributes by definition are unsorted, so this is an equivalent html code.
I want my code pass this kind of tests for any environment.
How do people achieve robust snapshot test?
I am using this dependency:
  "devDependencies": {
    "vitest": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^11"
  }

And my test is the next:
      it("match snapshot", async () => {
          const minDate = new Date(2024, 1, 1)
          const date = new Date(2024, 1, 1)
          const component = await mountSuspended(MyDayPicker, {
              props: {
                  modelValue: date, minDate: minDate
              }
          });
          expect(component.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
      });

